# R - Duplicate rows while changing values in a particular field

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `df` with `Name` `Date` `Count` as the fields. I want to duplicate each row `Count` number of times by incrementing the Date by 1 month. Here is my sample table:

| Name | Date | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 10-21-2019 | 12 |

I want 12 rows for John with dates incrementing for 12 months. Sample result:

| Name | Date | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 10-21-2019 | 12 |
| John | 11-21-2019 | 12 |
| John | 12-21-2019 | 12 |
| John | 1-21-2020 | 12 |
| John | 2-21-2020 | 12 |
| John | 3-21-2020 | 12 |
| John | 4-21-2020 | 12 |
| John | 5-21-2020 | 12 |
| John | 6-21-2020 | 12 |
| John | 7-21-2020 | 12 |
| John | 8-21-2020 | 12 |
| John | 9-21-2020 | 12 |

There might be many other columns which i simply want to duplicate except for `Date` column. How can i achieve this in R?

Comment: It might be very useful to improve the post with a minimal reproducible example:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a dplyr method:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  slice(rep(1, Count)) %>%
  group_by(rn) %>%
  mutate(Date = seq(Date[1], by = "months", length.out = n())) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-rn)
# # A tibble: 12 x 3
#    Name  Date       Count
#    <chr> <date>     <int>
#  1 John  2019-10-21    12
#  2 John  2019-11-21    12
#  3 John  2019-12-21    12
#  4 John  2020-01-21    12
#  5 John  2020-02-21    12
#  6 John  2020-03-21    12
#  7 John  2020-04-21    12
#  8 John  2020-05-21    12
#  9 John  2020-06-21    12
# 10 John  2020-07-21    12
# 11 John  2020-08-21    12
# 12 John  2020-09-21    12
```

Quick walk-through:

- add `rn` so that I can most easily/confidently group by them later (since each Name/Date combination may occur any number of times, I'm inferring);
- `slice(rep(1, Count))` selects the first row, `Count` times, giving the repeated rows desired; since this is by-row already (`rowwise()`), this just expands the rows by `Count`
- `seq(Date[1], ...)` because at this point, `Date` is a vector that is likely more than 1, we really only care about the first of the repeated dates; `by="months" and` length.out=n()` ensure we get the interval and span/period desired to fill the number of rows
- some cleanup with `ungroup()` and removing the `rn` helper column

---

### Update

If you need the day-of-month (`dom`) to be the lesser of the starting `dom` and the number of days in said month, then try this.

That is, with `"2019-01-31"`, sequencing by month will not step to `"2019-02-31"` (does not exist), it'll jump to `"2019-03-03"`. If you need it to jump to `"2019-02-28"` (since that is the last day of that month), then try this function. (We are now relying on the `lubridate` package.)

```r
seq_similar_dom <- function(first, length.out) {
  dom <- lubridate::day(first)
  month1 <- first - dom + 1L
  months1 <- seq(month1, by = "months", length.out = length.out)
  months1 - 1L + pmin(dom, lubridate::days_in_month(months1))
}
```

Let's update our example and try it with a couple of corner-cases.

First, if the `dom` for a particular entry is 28 or less, then this will work exactly the same. If it is 29 or higher, though ...

```r
dat$Date <- as.Date("2014-07-31")
dat %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  slice(rep(1, Count)) %>%
  group_by(rn) %>%
  mutate(Date = seq_similar_dom(Date[1], length.out = n())) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-rn)
# # A tibble: 12 x 3
#    Name  Date       Count
#    <chr> <date>     <int>
#  1 John  2014-07-31    12
#  2 John  2014-08-31    12
#  3 John  2014-09-30    12
#  4 John  2014-10-31    12
#  5 John  2014-11-30    12
#  6 John  2014-12-31    12
#  7 John  2015-01-31    12
#  8 John  2015-02-28    12
#  9 John  2015-03-31    12
# 10 John  2015-04-30    12
# 11 John  2015-05-31    12
# 12 John  2015-06-30    12

dat$Date <- as.Date("2019-01-31")
dat %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  slice(rep(1, Count)) %>%
  group_by(rn) %>%
  mutate(Date = seq_similar_dom(Date[1], length.out = n())) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-rn)
# # A tibble: 12 x 3
#    Name  Date       Count
#    <chr> <date>     <int>
#  1 John  2019-01-31    12
#  2 John  2019-02-28    12
#  3 John  2019-03-31    12
#  4 John  2019-04-30    12
#  5 John  2019-05-31    12
#  6 John  2019-06-30    12
#  7 John  2019-07-31    12
#  8 John  2019-08-31    12
#  9 John  2019-09-30    12
# 10 John  2019-10-31    12
# 11 John  2019-11-30    12
# 12 John  2019-12-31    12
```

---

Data:

```r
dat <- structure(list(Name = "John", Date = "10-21-2019", Count = 12L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
dat$Date <- as.Date(dat$Date, format = "%m-%d-%Y")
```

Comment: I think this is working. But when the date is 31st of a month, then it is repeating the months twice. Not sure if it is the same on your side as well. 

2014-07-31,  2014-08-31,  2014-10-01,   2014-10-31,   2014-12-01,  2014-12-31,  2015-01-31,  2015-03-03,   2015-03-31,  2015-05-01,  2015-05-31,  2015-07-01

Comment: Not all months have 31 days, so you need to specify what your preference is. I can't infer that. Do you want to "round" it to the end of the month? That (to me) is not an obvious assumption, and while it can be programmed, it is not nearly as trivial as `seq.Date`. What would you expect with `2019-01-31` and one month later?

Comment: I apologize for the incomplete requirement. The update worked just fine. Thank you so much for your help. Although its very slow considering the size of my data and also throws a warning which says "Warning message:
`...` is not empty.

We detected these problematic arguments:
* `needs_dots`"

Comment: I had another issue. It runs successfully by giving a warning :Grouping rowwise data frame strips rowwise nature. Because of this, only the first row is getting duplicated. The rest are not happening. Am i doing something wrong with the libraries?

Comment: I don't see that warning, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of nested dataframes to create a list column, and then unnest it.

In this case, it is slightly annoying because this seems to have trouble with the Date field. So we need to switch to Integer, and then back to Date.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

dat %>% 
  mutate(Date = map2(Date, Count, ~ as.integer(seq(.x, by = "months", length.out = .y)))) %>% 
  unnest_longer(Date) %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, origin = "1970-01-01"))
```

This will give you the expansion.

```r
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   Name  Date       Count
   <chr> <date>     <int>
 1 John  2019-10-21    12
 2 John  2019-11-21    12
 3 John  2019-12-21    12
 4 John  2020-01-21    12
 5 John  2020-02-21    12
 6 John  2020-03-21    12
 7 John  2020-04-21    12
 8 John  2020-05-21    12
 9 John  2020-06-21    12
10 John  2020-07-21    12
11 John  2020-08-21    12
12 John  2020-09-21    12
```

Comment: The date column is actually called "Start Date"  in my code and the count is always 12 for the case i was looking into. So i used the following:

`dat %>% 
  complete("Start Date" = seq("Start Date", by ="months", length.out = 12)) %>% 
  fill(Name, Count)`

I am getting an error which says 
`Error in seq.Date("Start Date", by = "months", length.out = 12) : 
  'from' must be of length 1`

Comment: Funny enough, my original, more complex deleted answer did this. I'll move that one in...

Answer (score 0):

A `base-R` method can be:

```
#Code
df1 <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), unique(df$Count)), ]
df1$Date <- seq(from=as.Date(min(df1$Date),'%m-%d-%Y'),by = '1 month',length.out = unique(df1$Count))
df1$Date <- format(df1$Date,'%m-%d-%Y')
```

Output:

```
df1
     Name       Date Count
1    John 10-21-2019    12
1.1  John 11-21-2019    12
1.2  John 12-21-2019    12
1.3  John 01-21-2020    12
1.4  John 02-21-2020    12
1.5  John 03-21-2020    12
1.6  John 04-21-2020    12
1.7  John 05-21-2020    12
1.8  John 06-21-2020    12
1.9  John 07-21-2020    12
1.10 John 08-21-2020    12
1.11 John 09-21-2020    12
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Name = "John", Date = "10-21-2019", Count = 12L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Comment: This is nice and succinct Duck, but I think it would fail if there were two rows in the original data frame with the same count. Do you maybe need to drop the `unique`?

Comment: @AllanCameron You are right Dr Cameron, do you think `unique(df$Count))[1]` can alleviate the issue?

Comment: You may need to `split-lapply-bind` if you want to do the whole thing in base R

Comment: @AllanCameron Yeah you are right, technically the number of rows should be a constant that is why I used this approach but there are 4 solutions now so OP can choose the best :).